# how do we add properties to a message?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

**Is it possible to set message properties (I think they are called UserProperties) when doing a binding?**

Within my function I'm doing an output binding to servicebus:

```
    [return: ServiceBus("%Detach:Done%", Connection = "Detach:ServiceBus", EntityType = EntityType.Topic)]
```

**How do we set the message properties when we are binding to ServiceBus?**

Comment: Which servicebus client (language) are you using?

Comment: the latest servicebus sdk .netcore c#

Comment: If you want to set a property on the incoming message, that's not possible. It has to be done by the sending party. If you want to set a property on the outgoing message, see the answer @roman-kiss has provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In async functions, use the return value or `IAsyncCollector` instead of an `out` parameter. For 2.x, use [Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#output---usage) instead of BrokeredMessage like `IAsyncCollector<Message>`.

Then you can set the `MessageId` property on the message. Refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52600299/adding-messages-to-iasynccollector-topic-output-with-a-session-id).

```
var message = new Message() { MessageId = messageId};
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public static class Function7
{
    [FunctionName("Function7")]
    [return: ServiceBus("test2", 
        Connection = "AzureServiceBusConnectionString", EntityType = EntityType.Queue)] 
    public static async Task<Message> Run([ServiceBusTrigger("test", 
        Connection = "AzureServiceBusConnectionString")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation(
            $"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");

        var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{}"));
        message.Label = "Hello";
        message.UserProperties.Add("abc", 123);
        return await Task.FromResult<Message>(message);
    }
}
```